# Find maximal subset of all non connected elements if Elements swapped in bubble sort are connected

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

In Bubble sort,whenever I swap two elements in the array (while sorting),I tie a rope between the element which are swapped.I need to find the size of the maximal set in the array in which none of the elements are connected with any other element after the bubble sort is done .

eg : { 1 , 3 ,2 }

1st iteration of bubble sort :

2 and 3 swapped so tie 2 with 3

{1 ,2,3}

2nd iteration

{1,2,3}
no swaps in this iteration so dont tie any element with any other element

3rd iteration

{1,2,3}
no swaps in this iteration so dont tie any element with any other element

after the end of bubble sort only 2 and 3 are tied together

Answer for this example is 2 because the size of  the maximal set  in which none of the elements is not tied with any other element.

the possible maximal sets are {1,2} (since 1 and 2 are not tied with a rope) and {1,3}  { since 1 and 3 are not tied with the rope }

Possible subsets for this array are {1} , {2}, {3} ,{1,2} ,{1,3} ,{3,2} {1,3,2},{ }

out of these valid subsets are {1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3} In this valid subsets {1,2} and {1,3} are larger subsets .The size of both the subsets are 2 .so the answer is 2.

Input :

First line of input contains T  - No of test cases

first line of each test case contains n ( 1 <= n <= 100000 )- number of elements in the array

second line  of each test case contains n elements of the array

example:

input : (from the example explained above )

1

3

1 3 2

output :

2

**MY APPROACH**

I think the maximal subset length will be the length of longest increasing subsequence and here's my code getting **WRONG ANSWERS**. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int bs(int a[],int x,int lo,int hi)
{
while(hi-lo>1)
{
    int mid=(hi+lo)/2;
    if(a[mid]>=x)
    hi=mid;
    else
    lo=mid;
}
return hi;
}

int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    int n,m=1;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
    int dp[n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    dp[i]=0;
    dp[0]=a[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(dp[0]>a[i])
        dp[0]=a[i];
        else if(a[i]>dp[m-1])
        dp[m++]=a[i];
        else
        {
            int x=bs(a,a[i],-1,m-1);
            dp[x]=a[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<m<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe first by induction that each connected component is an interval.

Observe next that, given a partition of the input into two parts, there is no edge spanning the parts if and only if every element in the first part is less than or equal to every element in the second part.

The connected components can be identified using a linear-time algorithm.

```
def count(lst):
    compmaxes = []  # holds the maximum of each connected component
    for x in lst:
        if not compmaxes or compmaxes[-1] <= x:
            compmaxes.append(x)
        else:
            while len(compmaxes) > 1 and compmaxes[-2] > x:
                del compmaxes[-2]
    return len(compmaxes)
```